# Titanium - Unable to implement radio button behaviour in Android, working in iphone 

Tags: titanium

Basically I am trying to implement radio button functionality in Titanium, this works in iphone as expected but in android it allows me to select multiple radio buttons.

Here is my code

```
var lastRadioBtn = null;
tableViewAns.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

if(e.source.id === undefined) {
Ti.API.info("---IN IF---");
} else {
    Ti.API.info("---IN ELSE---");
    if(lastRadioBtn != null){
        Ti.API.info("---NOT NULL---");
        lastRadioBtn.image = '/images/Radio_Button_Not_Selected.png';
    }
    lastRadioBtn = e.source;
    lastRadioBtn.image = '/images/Radio_Button_Selected.png';

}

});
```

here I created custom row(1 image, text) where image will be selected radio button(on table click) and unselected radio button when any other row will be clicked.

Everything seems to work fine , even in android I get control inside if condition for deselecting image but dont know its not working.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried a lot to find its solution but could not resolve it, I tried all property which may be applied(using e.row,e.rowData,e.row.children[i]) every case was working fine with IPhone but failed all the time in Android. I debug, condition was perfectly working with android but do not know why not changing image.

Solution :-
I made one array of images.
Now in table click I manage this array  and work with this array instead of table row and this solution works for both Android and Iphone.(Accessing element from array instead getting row of table and then access image.). I hope this will help everyone and this bug(what I am thinking)
 will be resolved.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
var lastRadioBtn = false;

tableViewAns.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

if(e.source.id === undefined) {
  Ti.API.info("---IN IF---");
 }
else {
 Ti.API.info("---IN ELSE---");
 if(lastRadioBtn == false){
     Ti.API.info("---NOT NULL---");
     lastRadioBtn.image = '../images/Radio_Button_Not_Selected.png';
    }
 lastRadioBtn = e.source;
 lastRadioBtn.image = '../images/Radio_Button_Selected.png';
 }

});
```

May Be this is helpful for you... Cheers...

Comment: HI MRT, Thanks for your answer but this did not work, right now when i click table row image gets changed which is correct but when i will select other row, only this row should be selected(previously selected button should be automatically deselected(Radio button behavior in android in which at a time you can select only one item)). In IPhone that works correct with my above code but with your code it is not working.

Also I could not understand what boolean is working in your code?